# NavigationView is not visible but item click is working

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, navigationview

I want to setup `navigation drawer` using `NavigationView`. Items are not visible but when we click on the empty area, particular item click code is getting executed. It looks items are invisible but clickable.

I've tried to play with background colour but it doesn't seems to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

**home.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout      
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/White"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".Home.HomeActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar" />

    <!-- Main Content -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</LinearLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/White">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/White"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/NavigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/White"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/YellowOrange"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/Black"
            app:menu="@menu/nav_menu" />

        <com.squawkinit.orionfreightelite.customview.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAppVersion"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**nav_menu.xml(Menu)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/dashboardMenu"
        android:title="@string/dashboard_menu" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/eLogMenu"
        android:title="@string/eLog_menu" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/emergencyMenu"
        android:title="@string/emergency_menu" />


    <item
        android:id="@+id/syncMenu"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/sync_status"
        android:title="@string/sync_menu" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/manifestMenu"
        android:title="@string/manifest_menu" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/groupMessagingMenu"
        android:title="@string/group_messaging_menu" />


    <item
        android:id="@+id/helpMenu"
        android:title="@string/help_menu" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/logoutMenu"
        android:title="@string/logout_menu" />
</group>
```

**navigation_header.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@color/White">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/navigationHeader"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/accent_material_dark"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivDrawerIcon"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/orion_elite_logo" />

    <com.squawkinit.orionfreightelite.customview.CustomTextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDrawerName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <com.squawkinit.orionfreightelite.customview.CustomTextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDrawerMobile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/LightWhite"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**CustomTextView**

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {

public CustomTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    if (!isInEditMode())
        setCustomFont(context);
}

public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    if (!isInEditMode())
        setCustomFont(context);
}

public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    if (!isInEditMode())
        setCustomFont(context);
}

public void setCustomFont(Context ctx) {

    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(),
            "fonts/DroidSerif_Regular.ttf");

    setTypeface(tf);

  }
 }
```

**Theme**

```
 <style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/Black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/Black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/Black</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/Orange</item>
    <item name="textColor">@color/Black</item>
</style>
```

[image: Navigation Drawer]

Comment: you have nested navigation views i guess both of them are clashing....make it only one and add all the inner navigations view attribute to the outer one and i guess it should work

Comment: Let me try @KunalParikh

Comment: Same output after moving inner navigation view to outer one. @KunalParikh

Comment: il try running your code tomorrow and see if i get any solution

Comment: @KunalParikh Any luck?

Comment: sorry brother couldn't run the code i was running on deadline... tomorrow for sure il run it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally!! I made it working.

In `navigation_header` root layout height should be `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" // This should be wrap_content
android:background="@color/White">

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/navigationHeader"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/accent_material_dark"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivDrawerIcon"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:src="@drawable/orion_elite_logo" />

<com.squawkinit.orionfreightelite.customview.CustomTextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDrawerName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="@color/White"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<com.squawkinit.orionfreightelite.customview.CustomTextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDrawerMobile"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/LightWhite"
    android:textSize="14sp" />
```

Comment: some times sloppy mistake cost us .Move ahead

Answer (score 1):

I could not 100% reproduce because I don't have your custom classes, but nested NavigationView gave me a menu which was offset above top.

So how about removing the outer NavigationView, like this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout      
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/White"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".Home.HomeActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar" />

    <!-- Main Content -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/White"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/NavigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/White"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/YellowOrange"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/Black"
            app:menu="@menu/nav_menu" />

        <com.squawkinit.orionfreightelite.customview.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAppVersion"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```